# How to add text with a transition in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
                $('#slider_title').text(var);
```

This adds the text from a variable to the paragraph with id "slider_title", now I want to fade in the text.

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: `$('#slider_title').text(var).hide().fadeIn()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#slider_title').hide().text('test').fadeIn();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='slider_title'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly were I was searching for!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#slider_title').text('fade').hide().fadeIn()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='slider_title'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css` transition. Performance might be much more effective with `css` solution instead of `js`.

You can do something like this:

```js
setTimeout(()=>$('.anything').text("wow!"),400);
```

```css
.anything {
   transition: 2s opacity;
   will-change: opacity;
}
.anything:empty {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="anything"></div>
```